# Can I iteratively slice the position I need from these separate lists and put them into another list 'coefficient' as shown below?

Tags: python, numpy, loops, jupyter-notebook, slice

What I want to do is iterate through the positions of each `p` list and put it into `coefficients` as such : `coefficients = [1, 2, 5, 8]` pause (in a sense) and run through calculations with this set of coefficients with `np.roots()`. After iterate to the next positions of each `p` and produce as such for the next iteration: `coefficients = [1, 3, 6, 9]` and then continue on for many more iterations.

```
p1 = [2, 3, 4]
p2 = [5, 6, 7]
p3 = [8, 9, 10]

coefficients = [1, p1[], p2[], p3[]]  # coefficients = [1, p1[0], p2[0], p3[0]] -> next comment
                                      # coefficients = [1,  2   ,     5,     8]
    
roots = np.roots(coefficients)
```

What I want:

```
p1 = [2, 3, 4]
p2 = [5, 6, 7]
p3 = [8, 9, 10]


#After parsing through the data for the 1st iteration:
coefficients = [1,2,5,8]

#Calculate it with np.roots()
roots = np.roots(coefficients)
```

And then the next iteration:

```
#After parsing through the data for the 2nd iteration:
coefficients = [1,3,6,9] # coefficients = [1, p1[1], p2[1], p3[1]] -> next comment
                         # coefficients = [1,  3   ,     6,     9]

#Calculate it with np.roots()
roots = np.roots(coefficients)
```

Comment: I'm wanting to automate this with a loop, such as a for loop.

Comment: Your task will become easier if you convert the lists to a matrix. Is that a possibility?

Comment: Yes this is a possibility. However, am I still able to retrieve the positions I want, and with only 3 coefficients as shown above?

Answer (score 1):

so I converted your problem in a matrix and displayed returned the result as a matrix as well. You can use this method and extend it to however many rows and columns you want. I am using matrix operations. `coefs` is the matrix containing a list of coefficients the way you wanted and `roots` contains the roots of those coefficients.

```py
import numpy as np
# Let n be number of rows and m be number of columns

n = 3 # or number of lists
m = 3

# Save the data as a matrix
p = [[2, 3, 4],
     [5, 6, 7],
     [8, 9, 10]]

coefs = []
roots = []

for i in range(m):
    coef = [1,]
    for j in range(n):
        coef.append(p[j][i])
    
    # Add to the coefficients matrix and roots matrix
    coefs.append(coef)
    roots.append(np.roots(coef))

# Display results
print("Coefficient list 1", coefs[0])
print("Coefficient list 2", coefs[1])
print("Coefficient list 3", coefs[2])

print("Roots list 1", roots[0])
print("Roots list 2", roots[1])
print("Roots list 3", roots[2])
```

This is what the output will look like.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate your data like this:

```
coefficients = np.array([[1, 1, 1], p1, p2, p3]).T
```

Unfortunately, `np.roots` only accepts one polynomial, so you will have to plug them in in a loop.

```
roots = [np.roots(p) for p in coefficients]
```